# how to fix: flake8/pyflakes treats multiline comment before class as error

Tags: python, emacs, pyflakes, flake8

I'm using flake8 with emacs. If I begin a file with

```
# comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

It says there is no syntax error. But if I wrap it to:

```
# comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment
# comment comment
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

I get "E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 0" for the "class" line.

Is this a bug? Can it be fixed with a config setting?

Comment: Why do you *want* to put comments before the class? If they pertain to the class, they should be a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) inside it. If they don't, there should be whitespace to indicate as much.

Comment: In this case, the comments are implementation details, rather than notes for class users.

Comment: I see. In general: yes, you can configure the warnings you want, e.g. with `# noqa`. See the docs for the tools you're using. You can also extend `flake8` if necessary

Comment: If you consider this to be a bug, raise it with the developers.

Answer (score 1):

This question is here, because it was marked **oftop** on *emacs* site, but the actual answer is there: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13762

Anyway, this code is good:

```
class A:
    pass


# two empty lines above and comment comment comment comment
class B:
    """
    About class B
    """
```

This is good too:

```
class A:
    pass


# two empty lines above and a comment
# comment
class B:
    """
    About class B
    """
```

And this will fail with `E302 expected 2 blank lines found 1`

```
class A:
    pass

# comment
# comment
class B:
    """
    About class B
    """
```

The error is caused by one line between classes. Probably, this is what your question about

Comment: Thanks. It does not like multiline comments using triple quotes...